# how to add Material-Animations library to my project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

i want to add [Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations) library to my android studio project,i don't know how to add it to my project,there is not any `aar` file or gradle command in it's document
aren't libraries like this usable for other developers?

sorry if my question is too basic
thanks in advance

Edit:
solved,this is not a library!

Comment: It looks like it's not a library, you don't need to add it. It's as simple as using the code shown, it's like a tutorial

Comment: @HèctorGodoy oh thanks,got it.please write your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't need to add it. It uses android native libraries, so it's more like a tutorial, you can use the code without adding anything.